# Addition of angular momenta, coefficient in the |10> state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, hilbert-space

In Griffith's text, they apply the lowering operator on the |$11\rangle$ state to get the  |$10\rangle$ state. They show this result in two forms on pg. 185:

$S_{-}\left(\uparrow\uparrow\right) = \hbar \left(\uparrow \downarrow + \downarrow \uparrow \right)$

and

$|10\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left(\uparrow \downarrow + \downarrow \uparrow \right)$

Where does the $ \hbar \text{ go and how does the} \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \text{ come in?} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation is not normalized, which is the result of the lowering operator. While the second equation is the normalized state, you can check it easily by using $\langle 10|10 \rangle$.

Or you can use the normalization condition $\langle \psi|\psi \rangle = 1$ where $|\psi \rangle = Z \hbar | \uparrow \downarrow + \downarrow \uparrow \rangle$.

Comment: How do you normalize something with arrows like that?

Comment: @Logan Use orthogonality. there are 4 possible states (arrow set) here, whenever they are the same, the result is , otherwise, 0. Say $\langle \uparrow \downarrow | \uparrow \downarrow \rangle = 0$. So, the expansion $\langle \psi|\psi \rangle = Z^2 * \hbar^2 * (1 + 1) = 1$ and you will get the normalized states.